# How to use SharedPreferences in MySQL LoginActivity

Tags: java, android, mysql, sharedpreferences

I am trying to save user password and email when user launch app if user logged in first time it will redirect main_activity.java class but I am using MySQL API for creating accounts. Here is my LoginActivity.java

```
Button login ;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
EditText email, password ;
String EmailHolder, PasswordHolder ;
boolean CheckEditText ;
String ServerLoginURL = "https://tayyarlan.000webhostapp.com/android-login.php";
public static final String UserEmail = "";
String finalResult ;
HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
URL url;
String FinalHttpData = "";
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter ;
LoginParseClass loginParseClass = new LoginParseClass();
BufferedReader bufferedReader ;
OutputStream outputStream ;
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
String Result ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);

    password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            GetCheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot();

            if(CheckEditText){

                LoginFunction(EmailHolder,PasswordHolder);

            }
            else {

                Toast.makeText(Login_Activity.this, "Haýyş ähli ýerleri dolduruň!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }



        }
    });
}

public void GetCheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot(){

    EmailHolder = email.getText().toString();
    PasswordHolder = password.getText().toString();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(EmailHolder) || TextUtils.isEmpty(PasswordHolder))
    {

        CheckEditText = false;

    }
    else {

        CheckEditText = true ;
    }

}

public void LoginFunction(final String email, final String password){

    class LoginFunctionClass extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Login_Activity.this,"Loading Data",null,true,true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String httpResponseMsg) {

            super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg);

            progressDialog.dismiss();

            if(httpResponseMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("Data Matched")){

                finish();

                Intent intent = new Intent(Login_Activity.this, HomeActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra(UserEmail,email);

                startActivity(intent);
            }else{

                Toast.makeText(Login_Activity.this,httpResponseMsg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            hashMap.put("email",params[0]);

            hashMap.put("password",params[1]);

            finalResult = loginParseClass.postRequest(hashMap);

            return finalResult;
        }
    }

    LoginFunctionClass loginFunctionClass = new LoginFunctionClass();
    loginFunctionClass.execute(email,password);
}

public class LoginParseClass {

    public String postRequest(HashMap<String, String> Data) {

        try {
            url = new URL(ServerLoginURL);

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(12000);

            httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(12000);

            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();

            bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(

                    new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

            bufferedWriter.write(FinalDataParse(Data));

            bufferedWriter.flush();

            bufferedWriter.close();

            outputStream.close();

            if (httpURLConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(
                                httpURLConnection.getInputStream()
                        )
                );
                FinalHttpData = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
            else {
                FinalHttpData = "Something Went Wrong";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return FinalHttpData;
    }

    public String FinalDataParse(HashMap<String, String> hashMap2) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        for(Map.Entry<String, String> map_entry : hashMap2.entrySet()){

            stringBuilder.append("&");

            stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(map_entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));

            stringBuilder.append("=");

            stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(map_entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));

        }

        Result = stringBuilder.toString();

        return Result ;
    }
}}
```

Here is my HomeActivity.java class

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int TIME_DELAY = 2000;
private static long back_pressed;
private static final int MODE_DARK = 0;
private static final int MODE_LIGHT = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_content);
}


public void taryh(View view) {
    Intent starts = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, taryhsub.class);
    startActivity(starts);
}

public void inlisdili(View view) {
    Intent starts = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, StartActivity.class);
    startActivity(starts);
}

public void turkmendili(View view) {
    Intent starts = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, scndhalf.class);
    startActivity(starts);
}
public void edebiyat(View view) {
    Intent starts = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, scndhalf.class);
    startActivity(starts);
}
public void testler(View view) {
    Intent starts = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, scndhalf.class);
    startActivity(starts);
}
```

Actually I don't know where I write sharedpreferences code, The code of sharedPreferences must have to check firstly, if logged in goto MainActivity if not goto loginActivity

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid an extra network operation, you could check if there are any values in the stored preferences before `LoginFunction(EmailHolder,PasswordHolder);` and open your second Activity, and on your `onPostExecute()` save the credentials, because if you get there that means that it was empty. E.G:

```
if (CheckEditText) {

    if (hasLoginSaved) {
        finish();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Login_Activity.this, HomeActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(UserEmail, email);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        LoginFunction(EmailHolder, PasswordHolder);
    }

}

 boolean hasLoginSaved() {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String user = preferences.getString("LoginUser", "-1");
    String pass = preferences.getString("LoginPass", "-1");

    if (!user.equalsIgnoreCase("-1") && !pass.equalsIgnoreCase("-1"))
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}

  
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String httpResponseMsg) {

    super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg);

    progressDialog.dismiss();

    if (httpResponseMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("Data Matched")) {

        saveLogin(UserEmail, email);


        finish();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Login_Activity.this, HomeActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra(UserEmail, email);

        startActivity(intent);
    } else {

        Toast.makeText(Login_Activity.this, httpResponseMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


void saveLogin(String user, String pass) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("LoginUser", user);
    editor.putString("LoginPass", pass);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Comment: Thank you I will try it, if it solution I will let you

Comment: It's give cannot resolve symbol hasLoginSaved

Comment: I posted almost pseudocode, `hasLoginSaved()` has to be outside of  `onCreate()`, like `GetCheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot()`

Comment: this is very important for me can you help me for full code?